# NSURLConnection get URL

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

how i get the URL inside the following method ??

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *ought to* be able to do `theConnection.request.URL`, but you can't. Annoying, isn't it?

The simplest way is to just save the URL (or the whole NSURLRequest) that you were loading. If you're using multiple connections, you can store them in a dictionary. Note that `-[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]` *copies keys*, and NSURLConnections are not copyable; the workaround is to use CFDictionarySetValue instead:

```
CFDictionarySetValue((CFMutableDictionaryRef)dict, connection, request);
```

Answer (score 21):

Hey there's a comment from Mihai Damian that worked for me:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSURL *myURL = [[connection currentRequest] URL];
```

Cheers

Comment: On MAC OS X it was added only in 10.8  so it won't work even for 10.7. 
Adding the because i got redirected to this question while looking for OSX not for iOS for which this question is being asked.

Comment: you may want to use [[connection originalRequest] URL] if you're comparing to a URL that you opened the connection with.  In case of e.g. redirects, originalRequest will have the original URL, and currentRequest will have the redirected URL

Answer (score 4):

Of course the above answers work, and I am looking for similar solution.

Just found that NSLog([connection description]); prints something like:

> < NSURLConnection: 0x9129520, http://google.com>

So it is possible to parse the string returned by [connection description], and get the url from the connection, though it is kind of dirty.

Comment: This will no longer work in iOS 5; you can use NSURLConnection's currentRequest instead

Comment: @MihaiDamian do you know of a comprable thing for iOS5.  My program was working great until I upgraded to iOS5 now need another way to get the url from the NSURLConnection

Comment: **Never** rely on the output of `-description` for a class unless it's specifically documented to use a particular format

Answer (score 3):

You can get URL like this

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection

  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

{

    // release the connection, and the data object

    [connection release];

    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

    [receivedData release];



    // inform the user

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",

          [error localizedDescription],

          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

}
```

for more information you van read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    self.rssFeedConnection = nil;

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading url : %@ ", connection.originalRequest.URL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0 iOS 9 you can do it like:

```
func connectionDidFinishDownloading(connection: NSURLConnection, destinationURL: NSURL) {
        print(connection.currentRequest.URL!)
    }
```